# Generar archivo pdf con datos dinamicos de la base de datos

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un archivo de pdf, es como una nota que trae texto fijo y hay algunos campos a llenar que estan vacios y busco que se llene directo de la base de datos, como lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Muestra tus datos en una tabla y así puedes usar el plugin de jquery 
https://datatables.net/

puedes poner para exportar en diferentes formas no solo en pdf

https://datatables.net/reference/button/
esa seria la documentación por si te interesa